Open source release of the Solaris linker and assembler
Is there an open source release (preferably with a permissive free license) of the Solaris linker (/usr/ccs/bin/ld, part of the SUNWtoo package) and assembler (/usr/ccs/bin/as, part of the SUNWsprot package)?
Such a release is possible to have happened, because the Solaris kernel and parts of Solaris userland have been open sourced as part of OpenSolaris, later OpenIndiana and illumos.
Please note that in this question I'm not interested in the open source and free software linker (GNU ld) and assembler (GNU as), both part of GNU Binutils, targeting Solaris.
Please note that in this question I'm not interested in the proprietary C, C++ or Fortran compilers in the SUNWspro package, with product names SPARCworks, SunSoft Workshop, Sun Workshop, Forte Developer, Sun ONE Studio, Sun Studio, Oracle Solaris Studio, Oracle Developer Studio.
This is what I've found so far:

The first x86 binaries for the Solaris linker and assembler I was able to find were part of Solaris 2.4 (released in 1994-11). However, source code was not included.

As far as I know, Solaris 8 source code was briefly released in year 2000. Was the source code of the linker and the assembler part of that release? Does this GitHub repo contain the full Solaris 8 source release? I couldn't find a linker or assembler there.

OpenSolaris and illumos are both open source derivatives of Solaris, with source code on GitHub (OpenSolaris source, illumos source). However, I wasn't able to find the Solaris linker or assembler there.

Archive of binary releases of SunOS and Solaris.

This Solaris 2.5 source archive doesn't contain anything for i386 (only SPARC), and it contains the source of the linker, but not the assembler.



Unless this happened in opensolaris before Oracle took over I think you are out of luck. What do you need it for?

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: I'm just curious about the implementation, and as a completionist I'd like to port them to Linux. They would be a much smaller executable file than of GNU as(1) and ld(1).

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Where can I find the complete, original OpenSolaris sources?

You are aware that the tools - with the compiler, assembler and linker) are not part of the operating system?

I don’t think so.  There is a reason the modern versions of opensolaris have switched to gcc

If you look hard enough, you can find the Solaris/SunOS ld source code.  No surprise: It's based on the AT&T ld source code.  I didn't see the Solaris/SunOS as source code but the AT&T as code is available if you look hard enough and it's reasonable to assume they're the same thing.

Solaris is based on System V release 4 (original version). Here is the copy of the source of as(1) in  System V release 4 version 3.0 (later than the original): https://github.com/mamccollum/svr4-386-src/tree/main/usr/src/cmd/sgs/as

Looks like the migration to gcc in opensolaris happened around 2006: https://docs.huihoo.com/opensolaris/opensolaris-developer-reference/html/ch02s03.html

TL;DR The Solaris linker has been released as open source, as part of OpenSolaris (see links below); sources of the linker in previous versions of Solaris and SunOS are not available. The sources of the assembler have never been released. OpenSolaris contains and uses the GNU Assembler from the beginning, and not the Solaris assembler.

I have found the linker sources in OpenSolaris (ld and libld, last build is 134), not in OpenIndiana (first build is 147, the iso contains the ld executable program) and illumos (ld and libld).

SunOS 4.0.1 (1988-11-16) and 4.0.2 have been released for i386 and could be installed to the Sun386i desktop computer, also sold by Sun. The  SunOS 4.0.1 and 4.0.2 assembler and linker (targeting i386) was based on an early version of AT&T Unix System V release 3 (SVR3) assembler and linker. (Thus it had additions and omissions compared to the latest SVR3, and it had some incompatibilities, suchs as the as -R command-line flag.) Both were COFF i386 executables, and both worked with COFF i386 executables and object files.
Solaris 2.1 (== SunOS 5.1) (in 1993-06 for the x86) and later versions of Solaris have been released for i386, running on regular PC hardware. The Solaris assembler and linker (targeting i386) was based on AT&T Unix System V release 4 (SVR4) assembler and linker. Both were ELF-32 i386 executables, and both worked with ELF-32 i386 executables and object files. Unfortunately I haven't able to find an i386 (x86) release of Solaris 2.1, 2.2 or 2.3 online, but I was able to confirm this with Solaris 2.4 found on archive.org (1994-07-16), by looking at the error messages found in the assembler and linker executables, and comparing them with the SVR4 error messages.

By looking at the error messages, the Solaris 2.4 assembler (/usr/ccs/bin/as) is very similar to the Unix System V release 4 version 3.0 assembler (source: https://github.com/mamccollum/svr4-386-src/tree/main/usr/src/cmd/sgs/as), the Solaris one is based on the SVR4 one. Here is a more detailed analysis:
Similarities:

The as program file is a dynamically linked ELF-32 executable targeting the i386 architecture.
libc is dynamically linked (libc.so.1), libm is statically linked.
The input syntax is AT&T i386 assembly syntax.
The output file format is ELF-32 relocatable (object) file.

Differences found and understood:

Solaris 2.4 libelf is dynamically linked (libelf.so.1), SVR4 libelf is statically linked.
libm functions are implemented differenty, especially the error reporting of the pow(3) function.
Solaris 2.4 as provides both the jcxz and jecxz instructions, SVR3 only provides jcxz. They both emit the same opcode.
Only Solaris 2.4 provides these directives: #ident, .nonvolatile, .volatile.
Solaris 2.4 as has better error reporting: Nonexisting file says which file.
Solaris 2.4 as supports adding debug info to th object file, in the stabs format, as separate ELF sections, using the .stabn, .stabs and .xstabs assembly directives. SVR4 as can't add any debug info to the object file.
SVR4 fails with multiple .file directives in the input.

Differences in unused library features:

Solaris 2.4 libelf provides better C++ symbol demangling. The assembler doesn't use C++ symbol demangling at all.
SVR4 libelf supports reading COFF files. The assembler doesn't read ELF or COFF files.

Only SVR4 has these strings:

.config_header
AT&T UNIX mkboot

Only Solaris has these strings:

#ident
*%c%06d
.rel.bss, .rel.data, .rel.got (but SVR4 has .rel).
invalid address expression
out of Elf_Data memory, out of nlist memory
symbols must be in same section


A specific piece evidence about the similarity of these two assemblers is that both of them contain the following messages:

section type has already been set
multiply defined symbol
error: multiply defined symbol
out of Code entries
cycle in expression caused by .size
Cannot Open Temporary (rel) File
Assembly inhibited
no loop  boxes (with double space after loop)
Assignment to dot must be relocatable
illegal use of %cs
Syntax error - use bound mem , reg
can not override symbol binding
should be constant <= 7 and >=0
Predefined Non-User Section


Unix System V release 4 version 2.0 (released on 1990-07-19 by Intel for i386, can be downloaded from https://archive.org/details/intel-unix-sv-r4-v2) contains an assembler (/usr/ccs/bin/as) and a linker (/usr/ccs/bin/ld), both part of the Development Set - scde - C Development Environment package (SCDE = Standard C Development Environment). The as and ld executables are of the ELF-32 file format and they also target ELF-32. They also link dynamically against /usr/lib/libc.so.1 (also used as the ELF program interpreter).
The as executable file also contains the messages above.
Unix System V release 4 timeline:

1.0: 1989
2.0: 1990-07-19 for i386
2.1: 1991 (?)
3.0: 1990

Unix System V release 4 hasn't been open sourced by the copyright holders. However, version 3.0 sources are available here: https://github.com/mamccollum/svr4-386-src/tree/main/usr/src/cmd/sgs/as

OpenSolaris contains the source code of the linker (targeting both 32-bit and 64-bit ELF).
The OpenSolaris as(1) command is just a wrapper which calls GNU as(1) (gas(1)) and also m4(1) and cpp(1). Its source is here:

https://github.com/kofemann/opensolaris/blob/master/usr/src/tools/aw/aw.c

This is proven by:

Download https://dlc.openindiana.org/isos/archive/opensolaris/textinstall-134-x86.iso

Run qemu-system-i386 -m 1g -enable-kvm -cdrom textinstall-134-x86.iso on e.g. Linux.

Choose to get a shell.

Run ld and as in the shell.


The following searches provide evidence that the assembler implementation is missing from the OpenSolaris sources:

https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Akofemann%2Fopensolaris+imulw&type=code (no results for imulw instruction)
https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Akofemann%2Fopensolaris+movz&type=code (results for movz instructions don't match any assembler source)

According to the OpenSolaris documentation, for build 19 only Sun Studio 10 was used as the C compiler (providing the SUNWspro package), and from build 38 (2006-03-28) both Sun Studio 10 and GCC are used. However, the assembler and the linker may be somewhere else (outside /opt/SUNWspro). Here are some missing filenames and broken links:

sunstudio10-20050614.sparc.tar.bz2
sunstudio10-x86.tar
SUNWonbld-20050613.i386.tar.bz2
http://opensolaris.org/os/community/tools/sun_studio_tools/ (broken)
http://opensolaris.org/os/community/tools/sun_studio_tools/faqs/ (broken)
http://opensolaris.org/os/downloads/on/ (broken)
https://web.archive.org/web/20100716162928/http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+tools/sun_studio_10_tools (archived page, download link doesn't work)

Sun Studio 10 (705-1318-10) was released in 2005-01, it supported Solaris 8, 9, 10 and Linux as a target. It also ran on Solaris and Linux hosts.

illumos sources also contains the linker, but not the assembler. There is no aw.c or any similar wrapper in the sources.

If I recall correctly the C compiler for Solaris was a licensed product and not immediately available like we expect today. That was why gcc had a binary release for Solaris to allow bootstrapping the latest gcc.  In other words, you need to look for paid optional packages and not the vanilla Solaris sources.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: That's correct about the C compiler. But it doesn't follow logically that the assembler and the linker are not part of the operating system. As an evidence to this, the linker source code is part of OpenSolaris.
